# How to do I hide list results until input is receieved in the search box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Branch Email</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Enter your branch code..." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>



</body>
</html>
```

How do I modify my code so that the list items are not displayed until the user search for something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide all `li`'s . by default

```
#myUL li{
  display:none;
}
```

And on keypress in the `input` change their display to `block` instead of `""`

```
if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
  li[i].style.display = "block";
} else {
  li[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {

    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (filter!== "" && a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li {
  display: none;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Branch Email</h2>

  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Enter your branch code..." title="Type in a name">

  <ul id="myUL">
    <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
  </ul>



</body>

</html>
```

**Update:**

Update `if` condition to

```
filter!== "" && a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1
```

to handle the case when you backspace and empty's the input value.

Comment: But that displays all list items when you back space everything?

Comment: Also what is the best way to bulk import an excel spreadsheet with a name and website link into this code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the initial display items to be hidden, and then let your if statement not only check for whether or not it contains the string you're looking for, but also whether or not the filter is an empty string.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(filter) && filter !== "") {
            li[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL li {
  display: none;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Branch Email</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Enter your branch code..." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>



</body>
</html>
```